# Max of laplacian in polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$
\Delta u=0 $$ on $$ x^2+y^2<4
$$

$$
u=3\cos(2 \theta)+1
$$
on

$$
x^2+y^2=4
$$

don't find the specific solution.

what is $u$ at the origin? what is the max of u and its location on the disk $$x^2+y^2\leq 4$$

EDIT: Thanks for the great response!

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to the Dirichlet problem in the disk is

$$u(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n r^n \cos{ n \theta}+ b_n r^n \sin{ n \theta})$$

Here, you have cosine components $n=0$ and $n=2$ only, so the solution will take the form

$$u(r,\theta) = a_0 + a_2 r^2 \cos{2 \theta}$$

From the specific boundary conditions, we will find that

$$u(r,\theta) = 1 + \frac{3}{4} r^2 \cos{2 \theta}$$

At the origin, $u=1$.  The max value of $u$ in the disk is $4$ at the edge of the disk where $\theta = 0, \pi$.

Comment: I'm having a tough time following the train of thought. How did you know what the form of the $$u(r, \theta)$$ was and that n=0 and n=2. Also how did you find the origin?

Sorry I'm new to pde's with polar coordinates! Thanks!

Comment: The solution follows from separation of variables in polar coordinates.  I knew the specific form of the solution from the boundary conditions: because there is only a constant and a @\cos{2 \theta}$ term, those will be the only terms in the solution by orthogonality.

Comment: @chrisguuren: you're welcome.  If you found this solution useful, please accept/upvote it.